# Figma or Sketch? which one is better for design

Tags: figma

I get confused about using Figma and sketch so I want to know what is the difference and which is the best to use and why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a user of the sketch. it's been 3 years since I am using Figma as my design tool and it's improving day by day. Keep in mind design tools are not what you should be concerned about but the skill you have. you can even design on Paint even a few years before many big companies were using Photoshop as their design tool, in fact, some are still using it. So the conclusion is no matter the is you are using, you can design everything related to UI/UX. The boundary is your imagination

Answer (score 0):

Adobe acquired Figma in September 2022. Some key features require payments now.    Adobe stopped any development and put all efforts on sales. Figma will be another hated product like Photoshop soon.